# Hidden Field and View State Encryption asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, encryption

When enabling `viewStateEncryptionMode="Always"` on an asp.net page will hidden fields like this : `Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("txt_ConnectionString", (string) PortalSettings.GetPortalSetting("ConnectionString"));` become encrypted aswell or do I still have to encode and encrypt them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `viewStateEncryptionMode` property does not affect hidden fields, only the `ViewState`.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.viewstateencryptionmode(v=vs.110).aspx).  A hidden field will still display in the markup exactly how you have it set.  The `ViewState` will store values for handling server side coding so that the state can be maintained between posts.  If you need to 'hide' the hidden field values from the user, you should be encrypting the values before assigning them to the hidden field which will then be encrypted in the `ViewState` as well.